# Understanding if conditions - Java

Tags: java, if-statement

What would the if condition be using this example.

```
A - if true, B or C must also be true; Pass
    if false, B and C do not matter; Fail
B - if true, A must also be true and C can be false or true
    if false, A must be true and C must be true; Pass, else Fail
C - if true, A must also be true and B can be false or true
    if false, A must be true and B must be true; Pass, else Fail
```

I am not sure how to set this up. Here is what I think the if may look like:

```
//Not sure if the "or" needs to be double or single bar.
if(A && B | C){
   //pass    
}else{//fail}
```

The broken apart code for this logic would be this:

```
if(A){
   if(B|C){
      //PASS
   }else{//fail}
}else{//fail}
```

Comment: Whether or not "or" is a single or double bar depends on what language you are programming in.

Comment: Didn't know that, will update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the language you're working with it's mostly || double bars.

I think this will work:

```
if(A && (B || C)) {
     pass;
} else {
     fail;
}
```

This means if A is true and B or C is true pass, otherwise fail.

Comment: When I said depending on the language you didn't say the language yet haha.

Comment: I know I just updated it lol Anyway, did not know you could use "()" in if conditions. If so this is the answer, thank you.

Comment: My pleasure, if you need any more help don't be afraid to ask.

Comment: @TJF You can use brackets for grouping, and should do so to make it clear what you meant. It's also an easy way to avoid logic errors caused by the operators being applied in an order other than what you meant. For example, `A && B || C` would be interpreted as `(A && B) || C` - in other words, if C is true the values of A and B don't matter, and if both A and B are true the value of C doesn't matter.

Comment: Great input. Wonder how many false positives/negatives I have been having over the years for not using parenthesis...

Comment: Is there code to print that out? Like the code would print out the conditions that took place. So for the first case it would print F && F || T and the second F || T

Answer (score 2):

In Java, the difference btw single and double operators is that double operators (`&&` and `||`) are short-circuit (i.e. if the result of the expression is pre-determined, the right side won't be executed).

e.g. in these cases, `foo()` would never be called:

```
false && foo(); // evaluates to false
true || foo(); // evaluates to true
```

but in these cases it would:

```
false & foo(); // still evaluates to false
true | foo(); // still evaluates to true
```

Comment: I get that, the problem I was having was how to work past B if false but if C was true, pass. Using parenthesis should solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Would foo() get called for false || foo();

Comment: @TJF Yes, since the value of the expression depends on the return value of  `foo`.